# Using Razor View Engine with Nancy, .cshtml not an available extension

Tags: c#, razor, nancy, razorengine

I’m working on a project using Nancy on a Mac, and I’m editing my project using a standard text editor (Atom). I would like to use the Razor View Engine, and I’m trying to figure out how.

I included

- `Nancy.Viewengines.Razor": "1.3.0"` in the dependencies in my
  project.json file
- `using Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor;` at the top of my `HomeModule.cs`
  file
- `@inherits
  Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<nancytest.Objects.Task>`
  at the top of the View I would like to use Razor in
  (`task_added.cshtml`), which has an extension of .cshtml

But when I load up the project, I get the error:

> Nancy.RequestExecutionException: Oh noes! ---> Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException: Unable to locate view 'task_added.cshtml'
>   Currently available view engine extensions: sshtml,html,htm```

Is there anything else I should include for it to recognize .cshtml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it to work! Unfortunately, the view engine is built on code that will not run on a Mac. This solution only works on Windows.

I added the following code to my configuration file (`Startup.cs`), translated from the [Razor Engine Wiki](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine).

```
public class RazorConfig : IRazorConfiguration
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAssemblyNames()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetDefaultNamespaces()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool AutoIncludeModelNamespace
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

The line `@inherits
Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<nancytest.Objects.Task>` at the top of each View is also unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read: the [Razor Engine Wiki](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine) and [View location conventions](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/View-location-conventions)?

Do you have an opportunity to try out your code on Bootcamp, or a Windows machine to see if it's Mac-specific?  Presumably you're running on `Mono` as it's on a Mac, likewise have you got any other projects/ tutorials running on your Mac?

Can you provide more detail on what you have/ haven't tried?  Whether you have the tutorial examples working?

At a guess, I'd say your view files (.cshtml) are not somewhere where Nancy is looking for them.  What's your folder structure?

**Edit**

Sorry, I've read it again and obviously Nancy isn't picking up the razor engine (as it explicitly says so).  You don't need the using statement in the HomeModule, is's not referenced there.

Have you double-checked the project reference for Nancy and checked that it's been copied into the bin folder?

Enable the diagnostics ([Diags](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Diagnostics)) and look in the 'Information' panel, under 'Loaded View Engine'- this will confirm which view engines are loaded, though it will doubtless say the same thing.

Given that Nancy auto-locates view engines by scanning the loaded appdomain and private bin directory for any dlls that reference nancy and auto-registers the `IViewEngine` types, it strongly suggests that the Razor assembly isn't in the bin folder, or something similar.

Comment: I'm able to get Nancy working, just not with Razor. All the tutorials I can find use VS, none use DNX. 

The app works when I use Nancy's view engine, but I need to use Razor.

I loaded this up in a VM with Windows using DNX, and I'm getting the same error. The root path is set up correctly and it's looking in the right place (root/Views/task_added.cshtml), but the error message doesn't list .cshtml as an available view engine extension, which makes me think it has something to do with how Razor is installed.

The 3 lines in my post are what I've done to include Razor.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DNX, but looking at it, perhaps there's a conflict with how Nancy searches for assemblies and how DNX presents them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my story and how I fixed it, in the event that someone has the same issue:

I compiled my Nancy app and it worked fine on my development computer (Windows 10).

I sent the app to another computer via Google Drive, and my client observed the same error as the original poster here on their computer (also Windows 10).

The cause of the issue was Windows **blocking** the file *Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.dll* on my client's computer, because they had downloaded my code from the Internet.

On the client computer, I unblocked the file from the file *properties* context menu, and the issue was fixed.

P.S. I also unblocked the cshtml files first, but that did not fix the issue, at least by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. I am using Nancy self host on a top shelf windows service. My problem was I only has a reference to the core application, but did not have reference to the Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.dll in my windows service project.

To fix it, I added the Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.dll refence to my WindowsService project

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I too using it as self host. but adding reference to main project does not solve the issue :(